# multivariate integral of a function defined by an inner product

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral, fubini-tonelli-theorems

> Let $v=(v_1,...,v_d)$ be a vector in $\mathbb{R}^d$ and consider the aligned rectangle $R=[a_1,b_1]\times...\times[a_d,b_d]$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$. Calculate the integral $\int_{R}^{}e^{-\langle x,v\rangle} dx$.

I approached the problem from an entirely quantitative point of view as the question is asked in that way, but I also want to know the qualitative arguments behind my calculations. Here is my approach and result:

> $\int_{R}^{}e^{-\langle x,v\rangle} dx = \int_{a_d}^{b_d}...\int_{a_1}^{b_1}e^{-(x_1v_1+...+x_dv_d)}dx_1...dx_d$. At this point, using Fubini's Theorem and the fact that each function is a function of a single variable, I split the integrals according to the coordinate on which the integral is taken, which gives:
> $= \int_{a_d}^{b_d} e^{-(x_dv_d)}dx_d  ... \int_{a_1}^{b_1} e^{-(x_1v_1)}dx_1                       $, where for each $i=1,...,d$ we have $\int_{a_i}^{b_i} e^{-(x_iv_i)}dx_i = -\frac{1}{v_i}(e^{-b_iv_i} - e^{-a_iv_i})   $. Using this line of thinking which I am not sure, the result is:  $\prod_{i=1}^{d}   -\frac{1}{v_i}(e^{-b_iv_i} - e^{-a_iv_i}) $.

The part I have  doubt is that when I simply split the integrals into $d$-many integrals on the real line: How should I support this transition with a rigorous approach? Is "by Fubini's Theorem" enough?

Comment: Yes it is, since the integrand is always positive and the integral is not only convergent, but also *absolutely* convergent.